# how to use FastTelethonhelper properly in an existing code?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I am trying to implement fast_download in my existing code. The problem is fast_download module uses `await` which I am not familiar with. The official documentation is not enough to implement for my current knowledge. Is there anyone who can help me?

here is my code.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from FastTelethonhelper import fast_download
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
from tqdm import tqdm

api_id =
api_hash = ''


def callback(current, total):
    global pbar
    global prev_curr
    pbar.update(current - prev_curr)
    prev_curr = current


def download_media(group, cl, name):
    global pbar
    global prev_curr

    messages = cl.get_messages(group, limit=2000)

    start = 0
    print(start)
    for i, message in enumerate(messages[start:]):
        prev_curr = 0
        if message.video:
            print("\n{} / {} : {}".format(i + start, len(messages), message.file.name))
            pbar = tqdm(total=message.document.size, unit='B', unit_scale=True)
            message.download_media('./' + name + '/', progress_callback=callback)
            # fast_download(client, message.video, download_folder = './' + name + '/', progress_bar_function=callback)
            pbar.close()


with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
        limit=500,
        hash=0,
    ))

    title = 'channel_name'  # Title for channel
    channel = client(GetFullChannelRequest(title))
    download_media(channel.full_chat, client, "directory_name")
```

I was expecting to enhance download speed of telethon api. Download speed of some files are limited to 100 kbs, which is too slow for large files. I have already implemented a code to use with telethon built-in module "download_media".

Comment: Please reduce your code and create little example and the line which shows error. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define a async function

```
async def download_media(group, cl, name):
    ...
    await fast_download(client, message, download_folder = './' + name + '/')
    ...
```

And to call the function you need to

```
import asyncio
asyncio.run(download_media(channel.full_chat, client, "directory_name"))
```

Also the progress bar function in fast telethon library is to check the progress of download within telegram. for it to work you also need to provide `reply` message to show progressbar on your callback function may not work as expected with this. And you dont have to pass `message.video`, only the `message` itself